# Vim: run Ex command on specified lines, ignoring folds

Tags: vim, folding, ex

When running an Ex command in Vim on range of lines, the range is always extended to cover adjacent folds (which is documented in `:help fold-behavior`). For example, given the following file:

```
int foo() {
  foobar();
}
```

the `:2s/o//n` command (i.e. counting o's in second line), will print:

```
2 matches on 1 line
```

However, if I fold the whole file, I get:

```
4 matches on 2 lines
```

Is there any way to override / workaround this behavior? I want to run my command on precisely specified range of lines; I don't care about folds.

Comment: I've found out that I can check whether a specific line is folded using `foldclosed` and `foldclosedend` methods. This at least allows detecting the problematic situation.

Comment: If everything else fails: disable folds, do your thing, re-enable folds.

Comment: @SatoKatsura : thanks, I just tried it and it works remarkably well. I'm surprised that all folds survive such operation. Do you know if there's anything else to watch for (e.g. any side effect of this toggling)?

Comment: As far as I know there are no side effects.  The problem with such toggle is that it involves screen refreshes, and that's insanely expensive for a simple regexp match.

Comment: I'm using your idea successfully. Please turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.